# jquery isFunction deprecated

Tags: jquery, deprecated

I get a deprecated message. How should i rewrite the isFunction code in this jquery code?

```
    fit($img, ($.isFunction(specialMeasures) ? specialMeasures() : specialMeasures) || measures, method || dataFrame.fit || opts.fit, position || dataFrame.position || opts.position);

        function fit ($el, measuresToFit, method, position) {
           do your stuff
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: [In most cases, its use can be replaced by typeof x === "function"](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.isfunction/)

Comment: Hi i know..  but how to apply that to above example code? like this?


      fit($img, (specialMeasures==="function" ? specialMeasures() : specialMeasures) || measures, method || dataFrame.fit || opts.fit, position || dataFrame.position || opts.position);

Comment: Just replace the X with your function name: `if(typeof specialMeasures === "function" )`

Comment: i can't use if( condtion ) { do something}  That is why i asked in the first place. Look at the given code example.Can i use it like this?

'(typeof specialMeasures === "function" ?  specialMeasures() : specialMeasures)'

so i get this

` fit($img, (typeof specialMeasures==="function" ? specialMeasures() : specialMeasures) || measures, method || dataFrame.fit || opts.fit, position || dataFrame.position || opts.position); `

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It does not matter if the condition is in an `if` block or used inside a ternary operator.So yes, your code should work.

Answer (score 2):

create a global function.. may be on the top of the js file..

```
  function isFunction(func){
    return typeof func === "function";
  }
```

And wherever this function is called i.e.

Your code.

```
fit($img, ($.isFunction(specialMeasures) ? ......
```

New code..

```
 fit($img, (isFunction(specialMeasures) ?  ......
```

just remove $. (Dollar sign and dot). so function on this page which you created will be called and work smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

```
    fit($img, ($.isFunction(specialMeasures) ? specialMeasures() : specialMeasures) || measures, method || dataFrame.fit || opts.fit, position || dataFrame.position || opts.position);

    function fit ($el, measuresToFit, method, position) {
       do your stuff
    }
```

Becomes:

```
    fit($img, ((typeof specialMeasures == "function") ? specialMeasures() : specialMeasures) || measures, method || dataFrame.fit || opts.fit, position || dataFrame.position || opts.position);

    function fit ($el, measuresToFit, method, position) {
       do your stuff
    }
```